# How to configure path for containerd-shim-runc-v2 in docker in an Linux RHEL 8.9 env

Tags: docker

I have installed docker on a linux vm with OS as RHEL 8.9

Docker version 24.0.7, build afdd53b

Client: Docker Engine - Community
Version:    24.0.7
Context:    default
Debug Mode: false
Plugins:
buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc.)
Version:  v0.12.1
Path:     /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-buildx
compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc.)
Version:  v2.24.2
Path:     /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose

Server:
Containers: 9
Running: 0
Paused: 0
Stopped: 9
Images: 4
Server Version: 24.0.7
Storage Driver: overlay2
Backing Filesystem: xfs
Supports d_type: true
Using metacopy: false
Native Overlay Diff: true
userxattr: false
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Cgroup Version: 1
Plugins:
Volume: local
Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries
splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: a1496014c916f9e62104b33d1bb5bd03b0858e59
runc version: v1.1.11-0-g4bccb38
init version: de40ad0
Security Options:
seccomp
Profile: builtin
Kernel Version: 4.18.0-513.9.1.el8_9.x86_64
Operating System: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.9 (Ootpa)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 6
Total Memory: 31.1GiB
Name: *******
ID: 7f7365dd-dec1-49fe-9cdb-97f42819afca
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode: false
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false

While running docker run , getting error:

> docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to start shim: start failed: : fork/exec /usr/local/bin/containerd-shim-runc-v2: no such file or directory: unknown.
> ERRO[0000] error waiting for container:

I have the containerd-shim-runc-v2 file in path /usr/bin . Where can I change the path to point to /usr/bin instead of /usr/local/bin ?

I tried to change the config to point to /usr/bin instead of /usr/local/bin , but could not find where to do this.